# Live agent deployment api contact not set on case

Tags: liveagent, livechattranscript

We're using the live agent deployment api and running into an issue with saving the contact related to the case.

I'm following a code sample located [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.live_agent_dev.meta/live_agent_dev/live_agent_deployment_api_code_sample.htm). Line 42 shows them attempting to attach a contact to a case.

Ironically, in the code it states it is setting the contact on the Case, however, in the screen shots provided there is no Contact on the case. :/

Here is the code we are using

```
function initLiveAgent(UserModel){
                liveagent.setName(UserModel.contact.FirstName + ' ' + UserModel.contact.LastName);
                liveagent.addCustomDetail('Contact_LastName', UserModel.contact.LastName);
                liveagent.addCustomDetail('Contact_ID', UserModel.contact.Id);
                liveagent.addCustomDetail('Case_Origin', 'Online Chat');
                liveagent.findOrCreate('Contact')
                         .map('Id','Contact_ID',true,true,false);
                liveagent.findOrCreate('Contact')
                         .saveToTranscript('ContactId')
                         .linkToEntity('Case','ContactId')
                         .showOnCreate();
                liveagent.findOrCreate('Case')
                         .map('Origin','Case_Origin',false, false,true)
                         .saveToTranscript('caseid')
                         .showOnCreate();

                liveagent.init('https://d.{!LiveAgentURL}/chat', '{!LiveAgentInitIdOne}', '{!LiveAgentInitIdTwo}');
            }
```

Does anyone have a ***working example*** of the contact being saved on the case object?

Comment: That's just JS for the chat window, not for the case. The case gets created from that window using the link that's created by the JS. It has to be linked to your org, etc. Make certain all of your links are correct.

Comment: I am facing same issue. I worked in the begining but now contact is not saved on case. Liveagent creates new contact and links that contact to case but does not find existing contact and link to case. Please let me know how you troubleshoot this. Kajal H

Comment: @Kajal we opened a ticket with salesforce support but ended up closing it because it was low on our priority. After a few webex sessions it was clear the support agents didn't have much experience with live agent support either.